# my scale animation doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I have this element:

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/cameraProgressBar"
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="15dp" 
   android:background = "#ffffff" 
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

and this animation code:

```
mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.cameraProgressBar);
```

.

```
 private void showGlassProgressBar(final Runnable onAnimationEnd) {

    float screenWidth = myManager.GetScreenWidth();


    ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1F, screenWidth, // Start and end values for the X
                                                                   // axis
                                                         // scaling
        1F, 1F, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f, // Pivot point of X scaling
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f); // Pivot point of Y scaling

    scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    scaleAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        AppService.Post(onAnimationEnd);

      }
    });    
    scaleAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    scaleAnim.setDuration(3 * 1000);
    mProgressBar.startAnimation(scaleAnim);

  }
```

I want to prolong a one dp dot to a full line (x asix)

but the animation is over and nothing is seen.

Comment: is mProgressBar one pixel wide view?

Comment: yes, that's the xml i have added

Comment: you have layout_width="1dp" not px

Comment: then its 1dp. why? does this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the signature is X-scale (start,end) and Y-scale.

meaning no absolute X-size `screenWidth`

better change:

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1F, screenWidth, 
    1F, 1F,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f, // Pivot point of X scaling
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
```

with:

```
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation((float) 0.0, (float) 1.0,
    1F, 1F,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
```